# Idle connection - timeout - XMPP connect

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp

I am using the [XMPPStream](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) XMPP framework and I've the following 
error:

```
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams">
    <connection-timeout xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams">
    </connection-timeout>
    <text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams" lang="en">Idle connection
    </text>
</stream:error>
```

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
let xmppStream = XMPPStream()
xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: .main)

let jabberID = "emad@chat.address.net"
xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: jabberID)

do {
    try xmppStream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
} catch {
    print("Something went wrong!")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue. I fix that. go to this link [XMPP connect will error connection-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747578/xmpp-connect-will-error-connection-timeout)

you have a problem in delegate functions. go and fix it